# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assets/img vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have following structure:

```
-src
  -assets
    -css
    -img
    -js
```

In my style.css I have this line:

```
background: url(~assets/img/arrows.png) no-repeat;
```

And get this error

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assets/img/arrows.png'`

what do I do?

I tried to write `./assets/`, `../assets/` , `./src/assets` still doesn't work

Comment: use ../img/arrows.png if your style.css file in css folder...

Comment: Where is your `style.css` file??

Comment: Did you find a solution now ?

Answer (score 1):

This issue can come up in Nuxt.js projects. If you're seeing this issue there, you'll have to either use a tilde (`~`) with no slash in front of the absolute path or you have to use a tilde and an at sign (`@`), so either this:

```
background-image: url('~assets/img/arrows.png');
```

Or this:

```
background-image: url('~@/assets/img/arrows.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've imported the css file in `App.vue` or any other `.vue` file make sure the url is relative to that `*.vue` file